# Select query with where condition in same table

Tags: sql

Could you please suggest below query.

I have table Customer

| No | Name | ChainCode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CD01 | TOYOTA | CD02 |
| CD02 | MAIN-TOYOTA |  |

I try to query by

```
Select No_
  ,Name
  ,ChainCode
  ,(Select Name from Customer as CompanyName where ChainCode = No_)
From Customer
Where No = CD01
```

The result I got:

| No | Name | ChainCode | CompanyName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CD01 | TOYOTA | CD02 |  |

What's I expect to get:

| No | Name | ChainCode | CompanyName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CD01 | TOYOTA | CD02 | MAIN-TOYOTA |

Comment: What Database you are using?

Comment: What is the different between Name and CompanyName? Since 'TOYOTA' and 'MAIN-TOYOTA' are stored in the same column Name in the table Customer, how do you link them with each other?

Comment: I'd expect an error here, you need to delimit string literals. E.g. `'CD01'`.

Comment: @TheKNVB i'm using SQL2016 (not sure this answer you)

Comment: @DVT Main TOYATA it's like Head office & TOYOTA it's like parent company. imagine customer table store many company (Ex: TOYOTA/ISUZU/MASDA...)

Comment: @TumSomboun: What is the logic you would differentiate them INSIDE that column?

Comment: @DVT : Basically we have customer data for many company such as TOYATO/ISUZU/MASDA as I told. each company we also have head office and their branch in our customer data Bec. we have service for all of them. In the chaincode field we put the head office code. it's using for when we want to know how many branch for each company

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using SQL Server you can try the cross apply key word, I am sure there are equivalents in other DB platforms.. else all you needed were table alias in your query

```
select T.NUM, T.Name, T.ChainCode, (select Name  from Customer where NUM = T.ChainCode) as CompanyName from Customer T  where num = 'CD01'
```

SQL Server solution

```
declare @Customer table
(
NUM varchar(10),
Name varchar(50),
ChainCode varchar(10)
)

insert into @Customer values
('CD01','TOYOTA','CD02'),
('CD02','MAIN-TOYOTA',null)

--select * from @tab

-- sql server
select NUM, Name, ChainCode, CompanyName
from @Customer T cross apply (select Name as CompanyName from @Customer where NUM = T.ChainCode) as TC
```

Comment: The similar ANSI/ISO SQL functionality is a _lateral derived table_. `... cross join lateral (select ...  from Customer where no_ = T.ChainCode)`

Comment: Thanks a lot Bro, it's working with this script

Comment: @jarlh: what query should be if i want to get result as below:

No         | Name             |ChainCode | CompanyName
CD01 | TOYOTA             |CD02         | MAIN-TOYOTA
CD02       | MAIN-TOYOTA   |                   |

Answer (score 4):

A generic way to do something like this is by using a self-join:

```
Select l.No_
  ,l.Name
  ,l.ChainCode
  ,r.Name as CompanyName
From Customer l LEFT JOIN 
     Customer r ON l.ChainCode = r.No_
Where l.No_ = 'CD01'
```

Comment: Emphasis on self _LEFT_ join.

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following:

```
SELECT a.No_,
       a.NAME,
       a.chaincode,
       b.NAME
FROM   customer a
       INNER JOIN customer b       
           on a.No_ = 'CD01' 
              and a.chaincode = b.No_
```

Comment: Is there a special reason why you used `a.num = 'CD01'` in the JOIN part and not as a WHERE clause? This 'Filter'  seems not to be necessary for the JOIN

Comment: For the field name 'num' is a typo error. I updated the sql.